# How to timeout on await for stream

Tags: dart

How do I add a timeout within an `await for` block? I'm basically waiting for a specific update within a stream:

```
await for (final value in someStream) {
  if(value...) {   // waiting on a specific update
     return;
  }
}
```

I want to add a timeout to this so that if the value is not found, for instance, 1 min then I can release the await.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use [`Stream.timeout`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Stream/timeout.html):

> When someone is listening on the returned stream and more than `timeLimit` passes without any event being emitted by this stream, the `onTimeout` function is called, which can then emit further events on the returned stream.
>
> [...]
>
> Calling `EventSink.close` on the sink passed to `onTimeout` closes the returned stream, and no further events are processed.

So, for example, if you want your `Stream` to emit some specific value if the timeout is reached:

```dart
void onTimeout(EventSink sink) {
  sink.add(someDummyValue);
}

const timeLimit = Duration(minutes: 1);

await for (final value in someStream.timeout(timeLimit, onTimeout: onTimeout)) {
  ...
}
```

or if you want to end the `Stream` if the timeout is reached, use `(sink) => sink.close()` for your `onTimeout` callback.

Comment: Nice! I assume when I call `sink.close()` the **new** stream created by `.timeout` will be closed and not the original `someStream`?

Comment: @Martin I am not an expert on Dart `Stream`s so am not completely certain, but I would expect it to close the original `Stream` too since they're single-subscriber by default, and `.timeout` would create a new `Stream` that subscribes to the original.  It'd seem pretty awkward if you had to explicitly close both `Stream`s when doing `Stream` transformations.

Comment: In my case, `someStream` is a broadcast stream so I need `sink.close()` to not close the original one. I can do some testing later today and I'll update here

Comment: @Martin Hm, not sure about that then.  You always could add a sentinel event to the `EventSink` and check for it to break out of the loop, or you could omit the `onTimeout` callback and catch the resulting `TimeoutException`.

Comment: If you close the `timeout` sink, it should cancel the subscription on the original stream that the "timeout stream" is getting its events from. (I think that maybe it currently doesn't, and if so, that's likely a bug.)
You cannot *close* the original stream, all you have control of is the subscription on that stream, so if the original stream is a broadcast stream, then only the one subscription will be cancelled.

Comment: Or, instead of `sink.add(someDummyValue)`, use `sink.addError('timeout waiting for someStream')` to throw an error that can be caught from outside of the `await for (...)` loop.